# How can I ensure our SolidWorks files are covered by the GPLv3?

Tags: licensing, gpl

I am in charge of a project on github that has files that are and are not code based. Specifically, I am worried about our SolidWorks files. How do I ensure these files are covered by the GPLv3 license?

Comment: I'm not sure the GPL is the better licence for data (or that your solidworks files count as data). Perhaps an [opendata](http://opendatacommons.org/) license or a [cc](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/) one would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

The GPL FAQ addresses this with:  [GPL for other than software](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLOtherThanSoftware)

> You can apply the GPL to any kind of work, as long as it is clear what constitutes the “source code” for the work. The GPL defines this as the preferred form of the work for making changes in it.

Presuming you mean the [3D modeling software SolidWorks](http://www.solidworks.com), then a design file would fall into this categorization that the FSF is intending with that FAQ.

As far as marking your design files as GPL'd, I would consider a couple of options:

- clearly state they are released under the GPL on your website
- if there are associated "info" files with the design files, you can add the GPL information there
- add a note block within the design itself indicating that it's released under the GPL.  Essentially, wherever you would place copyright information for the design would be a good place to indicate the licensing terms.